# How can I use one class inside another with the same namespace?

Tags: php, class, namespaces, autoload, spl

I'm using spl_autoload in my project, but when I try the following code, it gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Router\Route' not found in

//Router File

```
<?php
namespace Router;
class Router{
function foo(){
new Route();
}
?>
```

//Route File

```
<?php
namespace Router;
class Route{}
?>
```

Any help? I'm kinda new with namespaces.

Comment: Not sure you can declare the same namespace multiple times. If you want to use a namespace. Say 'use namespcace_name'.

Comment: Could you please show us your spl_autoload_register function?

Comment: I'm using the default autoload function "spl_autoload_register('spl_autoload')"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class from another namespace, but you can't have two namespaces by the same name (that defeats the point).

```
// In one file.
namespace Router;
class Router{
  function foo(){
    use Route as r;
    new r\Route();
  }
}

// In another file.
namespace Route;
class Route{}
```

Comment: Both classes are on the same namespace here.

Comment: So it doesn't exists a way of refleting these namespaces in my directory structure? I have Router and Route inside the "Router" directory, so my spl autoload would search for them in this namespace. Is there a way of doing this?